# Add a command to a C program in Linux

Tags: c, linux, command-line-arguments

I'm new to C and Linux. When run a compiled program in terminal, like:

```
./myProg --myCommand1
```

then `myProg` will do the job according to the command "myCommand1". I'd like add several commands to the myProg. I'm not sure if `char *argv[]` can be used for this.

Thanks.

Comment: It can be used for that.

Comment: What are examples of "--myCommand1"? A linux util like ls or an argument like -c etc.?

Comment: Particularly, these are known as **command-line arguments**.

Comment: "--myCommand1" is a string I defined in the myProg, like "--outPutNames"

Comment: @melodrama Then yes, you can use argv[i] as the two answers suggest below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be used. `argv[1]` is the first command, `argv[2]` is the second, etc.

Comment: Oh well, I thought it'd have started with 0. Thanks I didn't know!

Comment: @Pacane `argv[0]` is your program's name.

Answer (score 3):

check GNU [getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) for an easy way to parse cmdline arguments

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use your argc and argv arguments precisely for this. http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c/lesson14.html has a small tutorial on using them.

Answer (score 1):

Most Linux command line programs parse their arguments with a C level routine called `getopt()`.  It has some advantages to just walking the `argv[]` array, basically it will handle argument rearrangements, short and long flags, help messages, usage statements, and a number of items that are now generally taken for granted in a well working command line program.  I highly suggest you take a day or more to learn about it.

While it is easy to add an argument to an `getopt` using program, writing the code that does something if the argument is set could be very easy, or very very hard, depending on what you envision doing, how well your vision is detailed, and how suitable your details are to being implemented by a computer program.

Comment: Though `man optarg` brings you to the right place, I think you mean that most programs parse their arguments using `getopt()`.